Error message in creating Datacap FASTDOC application. On the dropdown Application Template: Select 'Form Template' the error message appears
I am getting this error message when attempting to create an IBM  Datacap Fastdoc application using the Application Wizard.  The  task did not complete and I get the message below upon selecting Form Template.  Selecting Learning Template from the Application Template dropdown worked correctly.
Problem description: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at WpfAppWiz.WizardHelper.UpdateFPDbWithlnstalledPath(String selectedTemplate) at WpfAppWiz.WizardHelper .. ctor(String selectedTemplate) at WpfAppWiz.WizardWin.BtnFinish_ Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) The application wizard did not complete.

